# How to flip y axis in a bar3d() plot?

Tags: matplotlib, 3d, plot, axis, flip

I use `bar3d()` to plot a 3D barchart, and I'd like to flip the `y` axis. I've tried to use `invert_yaxis()`, but it seems effectless. I've also tried manually reverse the values in the list with `[::-1]`, but it didn't help either. It keeps displaying the 3D barchart in the very same way.

Any idea how can I flip the `y` axis?

Here's an example how it's *not* working for me (not even with 3D line plots):

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d import Axes3D

fig1 = figure(1)

ax11 = subplot(2, 2, 1, projection='3d')
ax11.plot([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4])

ax12 = subplot(2, 2, 2, projection='3d')
ax12.invert_xaxis()
ax12.plot([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4])

ax21 = subplot(2, 2, 3)
ax21.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])

ax22 = subplot(2, 2, 4)
ax22.invert_xaxis()
ax22.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])

show()
```

And the plot looks like this: http://we.tl/cqSsecVy6P

Thanks,
Daniel

Comment: You can probably set the `ylim`. If you first set the maximum value and then zero, the y-axis is inverted: `pylab.ylim(max_y, 0)`

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately doesn't help in my case... I think the `bar3d()` method somehow ignores this family of properties, not sure though... But I've tried all the suggestions I've found with Google (dozens), but neither of them had any effect on the plot. It keeps plotting (with the default view angle) in a way that both the `y` axis and the `x` axis increases from left to right, and I can't change that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly I think the problem is that `matplotlib` rotates the 3D plot. To remedy this just set the initial viewing angle using `ax.view_init(elev, azim)`. Taking the [matplotlib hist3d demo](http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/hist3d_demo.html) then we just have

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
x, y = np.random.rand(2, 100) * 4
hist, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=4)

elements = (len(xedges) - 1) * (len(yedges) - 1)
xpos, ypos = np.meshgrid(xedges[:-1]+0.25, yedges[:-1]+0.25)

xpos = xpos.flatten()
ypos = ypos.flatten()
zpos = np.zeros(elements)
dx = 0.5 * np.ones_like(zpos)
dy = dx.copy()
dz = hist.flatten()

ypos_inv = ypos
ax.bar3d(xpos, ypos, zpos, dx, dy, dz, color='b', zsort='average')
ax.view_init(ax.elev, ax.azim+90)
plt.show()
```

[image]
Here I have rotated the axis by 90 degrees which flips one of the axis but not the other.

Comment: That just worked like charm! Thanks a lot, Mister! :)